# Downloading and Playing mp3 file into internal storage

Tags: android, file, storage, internal, download

We are working on android application,in which mp3 files should be downloaded into internal storage in a background service. We have implemented this using with code snippet mentioned below inside an `intent service`,But when we try to play the mp3 we are getting an error,like player is not supporting this audio file. If any one has a solution for this issue,Please advise me for the same.

Code Snippet:

```
    String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra(URL);
    String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
    //  String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/trail.mp3";
    File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            fileName);

    File dir = new File(output.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/TRIALS/");

    dir.mkdirs();
    String path = dir + "/" +"trail" + ".mp3";
    File f = new File(path);


    if (f.exists()) {
        f.delete();
    }

    InputStream stream = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
        conection.connect();
        // getting file length
        int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();
        //URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f.getPath());

        byte data[] = new byte[lenghtOfFile];

        long total = 0;

        int times = -1;
        while ((times = reader.read()) != -1) {
            fos.write(times);

        }
        // Successful finished
        result = Activity.RESULT_OK;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    publishResults(output.getAbsolutePath(), result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Check if `urlPath` is correct.You can open it by explorer and check if a `.mp3` begins to be downloaded.

2.Compare size of the file that you get by explorer to the one that downloaded through your code.

3.If the sizes differ,that means download failure.Try to modify your code like this:

```
    String urlPath = intent.getStringExtra(URL);
    String fileName = intent.getStringExtra(FILENAME);
    File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            fileName);
    File dir = new File(output.getAbsolutePath()
            + "/TRIALS/");
    dir.mkdirs();
    String path = dir + "/" +"trail" + ".mp3";
    File f = new File(path);

    if (f.exists()) {
        f.delete();
    }

    InputStream stream = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL(urlPath);
        URLConnection urlcon = url.openConnection();
        stream = urlcon.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(f.getPath());

        int times = -1;
        while ((times = reader.read()) != -1) {
            fos.write(times);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (fos != null) {
            try {
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I remove some useless code and add `fos.flush()` before `fos.close()`.